# JPA mapping with two properties. Is it possible to include two columns(properties) in mappedBy?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping, one-to-many

There are three DB tables, say

1. Table A with primary key as aId,
2. Table B with primary key as bId, and
3. Table C with primary key as cId, with two more columns are table_name, and table_key

Table C can have entries corresponding to

1. an entry in table A with table_key=aId AND table_name='A'
2. an entry in table B with table_key=bId AND table_name='B'

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_KEY")
    private String aId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy=?????)
    List<C> c;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_KEY")
    private String bId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy=?????)
    List<C> c;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "C_KEY")
    private String cId;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_KEY")
    private String tableKey;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_NAME")
    private String tableName;

}
```

When I query either from table A or table B, I want to fetch all the associated C.
Is there a way to define OneToMany mapping to take care of this where I want to use two columns in the mappedBy or JoinColumn and value for one of the column is specified then and there - for an example in the context of table A, table_name='A' while table_name='B' for table B. One of the columns attribute value is known at the time of defining the mapping.

Comment: I'm definitly not sure it work, but you can try `@OneToMany() @JoinColumns(foreignKey = {@JoinColumn(name="col1"), @JoinColumn(name="col2")}) public List<C> c; `

Comment: @Zorglube w.r.t. the example above, col2 value is known. In context of A, col2='A' and it is col2='B' in context of B. Can these values be defaulted when I am defining these mapping in A and B respectively?

Comment: did you just read about `@OneToMany` `JPA` annotation ?

Comment: Yes, did not get much and hence posted the question here.